# Metaslider flexslider move:1

Tags: javascript, php, flexslider

I have been trying to fix this for some time now, but still no luck. On a Wordpress install I'm using metaslider - Flexslider carousel.

The images in the carousel have different heights, but those are resized to fit the carousel: Result: the images have different widths. That on itself doesn't cause any problems, but when I clik next/prev I need the carousel to move only 1 image at a time. Now it is just moving the entire visible part.

Could someone please help me? http://denkkamer.com/nieuwesite/projecten/

I read the code: "move: 1;" should work. It doesn't.

```
// Carousel Options
itemWidth: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Box-model width of individual carousel items, including horizontal borders and padding.
itemMargin: 0,                  //{NEW} Integer: Margin between carousel items.
minItems: 1,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.
maxItems: 5,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
move: 1,                        //{NEW} Integer: Number of carousel items that should move on animation. If 0, slider will move all visible items.
allowOneSlide: true,           //{NEW} Boolean: Whether or not to allow a slider comprised of a single slide
```

Complete code: http://denkkamer.com/nieuwesite/code.js

Comment: Adding pictures, screenshots, small code snippets etc is probably better than linking to a js file on a site that might change, if this is to be of any value to future readers.

Comment: Also, take a look here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/move-slider-one-at-a-time-in-carousel-mode

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the tip. I will keep the code.js online, promise. I tried the link you've suggested already. No luck. (not with 10 or 11).

That was the fist thing I tried. After that i tried the move:1 in the .js.